# Does Multiplicative Version of Azuma's Inequality Hold?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

We know that there are multiplicative version concentration inequalities for
sums of independent random variables. For example, the following
multiplicative version **Chernoff** bound.

---

**Chernoff bound:**

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent random variables and $X_i \in
\{0,1\}$. Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then for any $\delta>0$,

$\Pr\left(X \ge (1+\delta)EX \right) \le e^{-c\cdot(EX)\delta ^2},$

where $c$ is some absolute constant.

---

Now we consider **dependent** random variables. A slight variant of **Azuma**'s inequality states the following.

---

**Azuma's Inequality:**

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be (dependent) random variables and $X_i \in
\{0,1\}$. Assume that there exists $m$, such that $\Pr\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i|X_{<i}] \le m\right) = 1.$ Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then for any $\lambda > 0$,

$\Pr\left(X \ge m+\lambda \right) \le e^{-2 \lambda^2/n}.$

---

Clearly Azuma's inequality is additive. My question is that does a
multiplicative version of Azuma's inequality such as the following
hold?

---

**My question:**

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be (dependent) random variables and $X_i \in
\{0,1\}$. Assume that there exists $m$, such that $\Pr\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i|X_{<i}] \le m\right) = 1.$ Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then for any $\delta
>0$

$\Pr\left(X \ge (1+\delta)m \right) \le e^{-c\cdot m \delta^2},$

where $c$ is some absolute constant.

---

Note that the standard Azuma's inequality does not imply the
multiplicative version when $m \ll
\sqrt{n}$.